# Python - Modulo Operation as a Conditional

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I saw such a use of the modulo operator in a lambda function testing for primality. Can someone explain why the following statement will execute as long as i is greater than x if this isn't to my knowledge an actual boolean statement. It works with division as well if the numerator is greater than the denominator regardless if they are factors or not.

```
if x % i:
    # Execute random foolishness
```

NOTE: I have only tried this in Python and Java so if this works in another language I apologize as it is probably not a language specific question.

Comment: In Python, `if x % i:` is equivalent to `if bool(x % i):` or `if x % i != 0:`; see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: While it does work, this sort of thing has always struck me as too C-like to be genuinely Pythonic. Others, of course, might disagree.

Answer (score 4):

Python treats non-zero values as True, so `if x % i:` is the same as `if x % i != 0:`. It's just a quick way to test if `x` is evenly divisible by `i`.

Answer (score 2):

For digit objects python assumes every non-zero value as `True` and zero as False, thus the condition `if x % i:` will be True until `x` is not divisible by `i` , else it would be `False`.

```
>>> bool(-1)
True
>>> bool(3)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

There is also such criteria for other objects like lists or strings, if you have a empty list or string python will evaluate it as False and for other cases it would be True.

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('a')
True
>>> bool([1])
True
>>> bool([''])
True
```

Actually it's [*Truth value testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) :

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
>
> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__bool__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is a condensed for form of:

```
if x % i != 0
```

As long as the modulo is not zero, this `if` will execute. If a number is evenly divisible by `i`, it will not perform the `if` block.